# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\pi) \cong \mathbb{Q}[[x]]/ \langle \sin(x) \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series

If we let $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ be the set of all power series with rational coefficients then can we say that $\mathbb{Q}(\pi) \cong  \mathbb{Q}[[x]]/ \langle \sin(x) \rangle$?

Comment: Something to note: Usually $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ usually means polynomials with rational coefficients. Use $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ to denote the formal power series.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki If you look at what his question states, that is what they mean.

Comment: Yes I realize. Read the question. Let $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ be the set of power series with rational coefficients.

Comment: @bburGsamohT Thank you I haven't seen this before.

Comment: @TheBluegrassMathematician The problem is that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ already means something _else_, so your notation is innately confusing. Since there's a standardized notation for the object you're interested in, it's best to just use that notation.

Comment: Are you assuming any restrictions on where the power series converge, or are you viewing them as purely formal objects? @anon's argument works if we're talking about, say, all power series with positive radius of convergence, but if we want power series that converge everywhere, then $\sin x$ and $x$ are _not_ associates.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Usually formal power series do not take into account any notion of convergence. In that sense, they are more like infinite sequences than power series. But of course maybe the OP has different thoughts...

Comment: @bburGsamohT: Yes, that's my question. If the OP had said "_formal_ power series" that would have settled it, but "all power series" leaves some ambiguity.

Comment: @HenningMakholm My mistake, sorry!

Comment: @Henning Hmm, are you sure the power series for $\frac{x}{\sin x}$ doesn't have infinite radius of convergence? I don't know offhand.

Comment: @anon: It has poles at nonzero integer multiples of $\pi$...

Comment: Ah, derp. Nevermind! :-)

Comment: I was assuming formal power series. Not just any infinite series.

Comment: @TheBluegrassMathematician: Um, any infinite sequence _is_ a formal power series, and vice versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Lemma*: in any ring $R$, any power series in $R[[x]]$ with constant term $1$ is invertible.

*Explanation*. Every power series with constant term $1$ can be written as $1-xf(x)$ for some other power series $f(x)$. Then $(1-xf(x))(1+xf(x)+x^2f(x)^2+\cdots)=1$. The geometric series can be simplified to a power series in $x$ by expanding all of the powers $f(x)^n$ and combining like terms.

Note that power series in $R[[x]]$ are purely formal objects. For instance $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! x^n$ is a valid formal power series, even though interpreted as a function it only makes sense for $x=0$.

Since $\sin x$ equals $x$ times a power series with constant term $1$, i.e. $x$ times a unit, it is associate to the element $x$, and therefore $\Bbb Q[[x]]/(\sin x)=\Bbb Q[[x]]/(x)\cong \Bbb Q\not\cong\Bbb Q(\pi)$.

Comment: Very interesting. Clear explanation. Thank you!

Comment: It may be worth noting that for any field $k$, $k[[x]]$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $(x)$. Thus, $\mathbb Q$ is the only field that can be expressed as a quotient of $\mathbb Q[[x]]$.